# Reusable SplitView pane?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I have created a simple SplitView and I'm wondering if I can reuse the code in my `<SplitView.Pane>`? It's pretty simple, just a few buttons, but I don't want to have to include the same code over and over again on my different pages.

Or is there a way to template the whole SplitView and just modify the `<SplitView.Content>`on every page? I'd prefer to be able to be able to have the button handlers be global too so that I don't have the same 3 buttons coded in each page .cs file.

What would be the best way to do this?

**EDIT: This is for a UWP Windows 10 app.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your own user control to reuse the content of splitview.pane.

[UserControl class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol)

Here is an example, my code.. 'FutaLocation' is my usercontrol.

```
    <SplitView x:Name="Splitter" Grid.Row="1"
               PanePlacement="Left"
               DisplayMode="Inline"
               OpenPaneLength="500"
               PaneClosed="Splitter_PaneClosed"
               PaneClosing="Splitter_PaneClosing"
               >
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <futaviewcontrols:FutaLocation x:Name="futaLocation"/>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <Pivot x:Name="directPivot"
```

Comment: This is what I was needing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can make a server control out of it, you can resuse and configure however you like. If this is not possible, you can make a code snippet and then place on page and alter as needed.

Comment: From what I can tell, a server control is for ASP.NET? I can't find any documentation for UWP apps.